# Why does INNER JOIN multiplies all rows if I join on itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample table and I made a typo while joining. But it produces some results which I cannot understand. Could you please explain in plain English why SQL multiplies rows?

I know how to fix problem:

```
INNER JOIN @temp tfo
ON t.id_StationDeparture = tfo.id_StationDeparture
    AND t.id_StationDestination = tfo.id_StationDestination
    AND t.id_City = tfo.id_City
    AND t.id_District = tfo.id_District
    AND t.id_Street = tfo.id_Street
    AND t.Amount = tfo.Amount
```

However, I would really like to know why it happens.

Please, do not close my question

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(   
    id_StationDeparture INT,
    id_StationDestination INT,  
    id_City INT,
    id_District INT,
    id_Street INT,
    Amount DECIMAL(15, 2)
)

INSERT INTO @temp
(
    id_StationDeparture,
    id_StationDestination,
    id_City,
    id_District,
    id_Street,
    Amount
)
VALUES  ( 10, 11, 1, 1, 1, 0)
, ( 12, 14, 1, 1, 0,0)
, ( 16, 18, 1, 1, 0,0)
```

And my query:

```
SELECT   
  t.id_StationDeparture
, t.id_StationDestination
, t.id_City
, t.id_District
, t.id_Street
, t.Amount
FROM @temp  t
INNER JOIN @temp tfo
ON t.id_StationDeparture = t.id_StationDeparture
    AND t.id_StationDestination = t.id_StationDestination
    AND t.id_City = t.id_City
    AND t.id_District = t.id_District
    AND t.id_Street = t.id_Street
    AND t.Amount = t.Amount
```

I expect the following result because I am joining on different rows:

[image]

However, what I get is:

[image]

Comment: give an alias to "INNER JOIN @temp tfo" and use that alias in the join conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP states that the error is known and corrected, the question is why, when the error appears, three duplicates are being returned.

The answer is that because the `JOIN` clause is not comparing the two instances of the `temp` table, but instead comparing the first instance to itself, the query matched each row in `tfo` to each row in `t`. Because there are three rows in the table, there are three rows returned for each row. Add another row to the table and you will see that you get four duplicates for each original row.

Expanding on this: You are joining temp as two aliases: `t` and `tfo`. The `SELECT` looks at each row in `t` and then compares it to each row in `tfo` to see if the `JOIN` criteria matches for that set of the row in `t` and row in `tfo`. However, because your error matches the row in `t` with itself, for each row in `tfo` the `JOIN` is true, and therefore each row is repeated as many times as there are rows in `tfo`. Given that it's the same table, you get as many duplicates as there are rows in the table, so the results set will contain the square of the number of rows in the table.

Comment: Thank you, for your response. So it is like CROSS JOIN? Could you explain like for kid? I am sorry, but I really would like to understand what happens?

Comment: You are joining `temp` as two aliases: `t` and `tfo`. The `SELECT` looks at each row in `t` and then compares it to each row in `tfo` to see if the `JOIN` criteria matches for that set of the row in `t` and row in `tfo`. However, because your error matches the row in `t` with itself, for each row in `tfo` the `JOIN` is true, and therefore each row is repeated as many times as there are rows in `tfo`. Given that it's the same table, you get as many duplicates as there are rows in the table.

Comment: Man, you are super programmer! Now I understood why it happens. Thank you so much!

Comment: `Given that it's the same table, you get as many duplicates as there are rows in the table` - this part is obviously not true. If it was then the number of rows in resultset would be 6 and not 9.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: To clarify, the query returns a duplicate row for each row being compared, so the number rows in the result set is the square of the number of rows in the original table.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change table alias becasue your conditions are always true for non-nullable columns `t.id_StationDeparture = t.id_StationDeparture` and works the same as `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT   
  t.id_StationDeparture
, t.id_StationDestination
, t.id_City
, t.id_District
, t.id_Street
, t.Amount
FROM @temp  t
INNER JOIN @temp tfo
ON t.id_StationDeparture = tfo.id_StationDeparture
    AND t.id_StationDestination = tfo.id_StationDestination
    AND t.id_City = tfo.id_City
    AND t.id_District = tfo.id_District
    AND t.id_Street = tfo.id_Street
    AND t.Amount = tfo.Amount;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=52dd2fbabb6214698362f3c36385e48a)**

---

EDIT:

The resultset has 9 rows because `CROSS JOIN` is a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and 3 times 3 is equal **9**

> The cardinality of a set is the number of elements of the set. **The cardinality of the output set is equal to the product of the cardinalities of all the input sets**
>
> **|A × B| = |A| · |B|**

Comment: Still not clear why SQL optimizers in (most) modern RDMS will not error when encountering `t.id_StationDeparture = t.id_StationDeparture`, it should be clear to the optimizer you want to `INNER JOIN` right ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland For nullable column it will remove row from JOIN so no, it is not obvious.

Comment: true, but the optimizer already loads needed table structures so it knows if a column is nullable or not..

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I know how to fix error. But I would like to know why I got 9 rows instead of 3 rows if I do not correct aliases?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was rather thinking about the purpose of query written by developer. Optimizer is not trying to figure out **why** but **how** to get answer in most optimal way

Comment: @Learner You got the answer **(CROSS JOIN) - cartesian product (n times m)** in your case of self join you got 3 * 3 = 9

Comment: *"Optimizer is not trying to figure out why but how to get answer in most optimal way "* I know how optimizers work but in this case in general optimizers (or better said the parser) should detected that the ON clause didn't match up as correct INNER JOIN (filter/matching) because off the ambiguous nature off `t.id_StationDeparture = t.id_StationDeparture` part but that is mine opinion.. Also as the SQL standard drops this Syntax Rule for the ON *"Each <column reference> directly contained in the <search condition> shall unambiguously reference a column of T1 or T2 or be an outer reference."*

Comment: “are always true for non-nullable columns t.id_StationDeparture = t.id_StationDeparture” but I have three same rows in one row and one row in another row. Why I got 9 rows?

Comment: @Learner Please refresh the page and read about CROSS JOIN  which is a math concept of Cartesian product and about cardniality in set theory. Everything was provided already

Comment: Do you mean that my query is equal to “SELECT   
  t.id_StationDeparture
, t.id_StationDestination
, t.id_City
, t.id_District
, t.id_Street
, t.Amount
FROM temp  t
INNER JOIN temp tfo on 1=1”?

Comment: @Learner Yes, the condition for non-nullable columns is always true